# Viewing cumulative electricity usage

Tags: electrical, appliances, energy-efficiency, troubleshooting, saving-money

The [TED 5000C](http://www.theenergydetective.com/b-5000c.html) monitors real-time electricity usage. This, however, isn't so useful if plugged into, say, a fridge, where, presumably, the bulk of the electricity usage is going to come from when the compressor is on.

As such it seems like it'd be more useful to monitor the cumulative electricity usage. ie. from the moment you plug it in to the moment you unplug it or something.

Is there such a device?

Comment: I would bet that the TED does have a cumulative usage display mode. But do you really need that device or would the less costly although more limited _Kill a Watt_ meter work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the multitude of kill-a-watt type plug-in energy monitors will give cumulative kWh since the monitor was powered-on.

The device you link to looks like a whole-household energy monitor. There is a current-sense clamp for each phase of electricity supply into the building. I've used two different models of  these types of device and they both gave cumulative use (though obviously you can't directly track usage by individual appliances). They typically give a history of usage by day for the last week, usage by week for several weeks and usage by month for several months.

> The Gateway is the heart of the TED 5000 series. It stores 60 minutes of Second-data, 2 days of Minute-data, 90 days of Hourly-data, 24 months of Daily-data, and 10 years of Monthly-data and provides the communications interface to your computer. Your real-time and historical data can be viewed on your computer by the Gateway's Ethernet connection and its embedded Footprints Firmware